# How to encrypt already existing bucket using KMS CMK using SAM template

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, serverless, aws-sam, amazon-kms

I am creating a SAM template to create resources in AWS. But, S3 bucket is already created using another method (Amplify). Hence, my requirement is to use SAM template to only encrypt already created S3 using KMS key (CMK). Currently, S3 is by default encrypted with AWS managed SSE. I used below code to encrypt existing S3. Though the below code creates a new bucket with specified encryption, I thought that, since the S3 bucket already exists, it just updated the encryption type. But though the SAM job succeeded, S3 bucket's encryption was not updated to KMS CMK.

```
EncryptedS3Bucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties:
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionC-onfiguration:
          - BucketKeyEnabled: true
            ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              SSEAlgorithm: 'aws:kms'
              KMSMasterKeyID: KMS-KEY-ARN
```